# How to have Microsoft Virtual PC use 2 CPUs

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, cpu, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have XP mode running on Windows 7.

How can I setup multiple CPU usage (to boost performance)?

Answer (score 8):

Windows 7's Virtual PC does not support more than one virtual CPU per VM.  If you need multiple virtual CPUs then you need to look at an alternative VM system like Hyper-V, VirtualBox or one of  VMWare's products.

See [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprovirt/thread/85315945-82af-40b8-b63b-d9cccfcb99b1) and [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprovirt/thread/c29a02fc-1e48-4ecb-8c58-264d06ff55c5).